# After building app using electron-packager the javascript can't find images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron, electron-builder

The app works fine when I run it via `$npm start`. After I have built the app using electron-packager the javascript within the built app can't find assets in the images directory.

Example: I define the app icon in my main.js `var mb = menubar({width: 370, height: 210, preloadWindow:true, icon: 'img/icon/icon.png'});` It gives the error `Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'img/icon/icon.png'`.

If I load the image in the HTML it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `/img/icon/icon.png`?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah, Yep

Comment: Relative paths cease to work after packaging for distribution, you'll have to create your paths using `__dirname`

Comment: @JensHabegger this fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I've added the comment as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths cease to work after packaging for distribution, you'll have to create your paths using `__dirname`.